# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-python

I have such an erorr in Google Cloud: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'02:24".. Because of that my BQ table don't have any data inside. Can somebody help me? I am trying to implement Facebook Ads -> BQ connector (https://medium.com/beardsanalytics/writing-your-data-connector-from-facebook-ads-to-google-bigquery-670caeff8262)

```python
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logger.error('request to currencylayer error: {}').format(e)
            return e
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```html
   except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logger.error('request to currencylayer error: {}'.format(e))
            raise e
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).